# Does including scripts in the head makes loading slower?

Tags: javascript

`Google` says i have to put this files in the head of a document :

```
 <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
 <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
```

There are 6-8 scripts like this.

The point is that i do not need them before i load my `html`, only later.

1. does my `html` `body` waits till it load all of these ?
2. why Google explicitly advice to put them on the `head` and not after my `html`?

Comment: When the browser engine encounters a script tag, the DOM development is paused till the entire script is processed. Based on the size of the script, that takes its own time.

Comment: Use `async` or `defer` on the script tag to modify how scripts are downloaded.  (e.g `<script src="whatever" defer>` or `<script src="whatever" async>`  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

Comment: thanks, it is crazy so why would anyone advice you to put this on the head ? don't we want to first show our html ?

Comment: But if i use async, later i have more scripts to load (After html) that need this first to work and i can not be sure these loaded with async (?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> does my html body waits till it load all of these ?

If you detach the scripts using async your html body dont wait

> why Google explicitly advice to put them on the head and not after my html?

I think firebase recommends to add it in the body  https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

```
<body>
  <!-- Insert these scripts at the bottom of the HTML, but before you use any Firebase services -->

  <!-- Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and must be listed first -->
  <script async src="/__/firebase/6.3.1/firebase-app.js"></script>

  <!-- Add Firebase products that you want to use -->
  <script async src="/__/firebase/6.3.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script async src="/__/firebase/6.3.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: i am new to Stack Overflow :) thanks for the advice RobG :) :D

Answer (score 2):

You can attach `async` tag to those scripts to prevent them from blocking the whole page.

Comment: While this is a useful comment, it doesn't really fully answer the question.  Is body loading paused?  Why does Google advise putting them in `head`?  What does `async` do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

1. There's option which you can attach script with async event, so it cannot interrupt with loading html body. Example :
2. In my opinion, attach in near head because some people can forget to attach in the body. Not in after html tag, maybe before closing html tag. Some people code can be different.

Comment: Scripts must be in the head or body. If outside those elements, tolerant HTML user agents will just move them somewhere appropriate (noting that head and body tags are optional, so the user agent may put the head and body wherever seems appropriate). XML user agents probably wont.